# silverlight domain service don't allow return a generic object

Tags: wcf, silverlight, generics, ria, domainservices

I have a domain service running smooth, some expose functions that return generic lists of defined entity, but for some reason, I had add some common information so I created a generic object to wrap the collection with the extra information that I need return.

but when after made the change and try use the service in the client, the function don't show up in the context, I already search about it and what I found was attributes for generic IQueryable

my wrap class

```
public class Wrap<T>
{

   public String commonProperty { get; set; }
   public String anotherCommonProperty { get; set; }
   public List<T> items { get; set; }

}
```

in my service domain

```
public Wrap<SomeClass> GetAll()
{

  Wrap<SomeClass> myObject = new Wrap<SomeClass>();
  myObject.items = new List<SomeClass>();
  myObject.commonProperty = "some info";
  myObject.anotherCommonProperty = "some info";
  return myObject;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding the `[KnownType(typeof(SomeClass))]` attribute in the `Wrap<T>` class, the problem is that you need to include one `KnowType` attribute for every class in your domain (this is because you are making a polymorphic service).

And adding the `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(SomeClass))]` in the `GetAll` method in the service (this is for wcf services I don't know if is valid for domain services).

Answer (score 0):

**WCF RIA domain services does not support generic entity types.** `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` are special cases.

Your method was ignored because it did not match [supported method type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707373%28v=vs.91%29.aspx).
Before changes `GetAll` was recognized as Query method. You can force that by adding attribute.

```
[Query]
public Wrap<SomeClass> GetAll()
```

Now it does not dissapear silently. But generates compile time error instead:

> Type 'Wrap`1' is not a valid entity type.  Entity types cannot be
>   generic.